# I can't add a book that I've written that's not on Amazon

Tags: feature-request, jobs, books

Is there any chance that there will be support to my Careers profile for adding books that aren't available to purchase through Amazon.com? My book was published through Smashing Magazine and it isn't available there.

Comment: Adding books where?  To Careers.SO?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, on Careers. A prospect shows great knowledge if they publish a book, and being able to show that I published a book is a huge advantage for me.

Comment: I kinda understood your "SO?" when I wrote my last comment. I thought you were saying saying "so?", as in "why does it matter?" That's why I explained why I care about being able to add my book.